# How to delete an order programatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, orders, programmatically, delete

How can we delete a Magento2 order programatically? There's ways to do this in Magento 1.X. Is it the same methodology for Magento2 as well?

Comment: Try this one free extension https://magecomp.com/magento-2-delete-orders.html

Comment: https://gist.github.com/leek/f7fd2c41668b0f8a0a5f6e5209fe8f4e

Comment: Why note this? 55k installs, it is free. https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-delete-orders

Answer (score 2):

You should use `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface`.

```
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order **/

protected $order;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,
    ......
) {
    $this->order = $order;

}
```

Load order object by increment id and delete it.

```
$this->order->loadByIncrementId('XXXXXXXXX');
$this->order->delete();
```

Comment: Does this delete too related entities, such as invoice, shipment, etc...?

Comment: @RaulSanchez  Yes. But first you can check in development environment.

Comment: how to archive order programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code to delete the order.

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');

$id = 10; // your order_id 
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($id);

// $incrementId = 'xxxxxxxxx';
// $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

$registry->register('isSecureArea','true');
$order->delete();
$registry->unregister('isSecureArea');
```

**Note:** I used the objectManager for the demonstration. Always use dependency injection.

Comment: Does this delete too related entities, such as invoice, shipment, etc...?

Comment: I have the same doubt of @RaulSanchez this delete the order items and all the other entities?

Comment: can you please let me know how to archive the order from the script.

Answer (score 1):

### Method #1: SQL queries

Try to run the following query:

````
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

# Clean order history
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`;

# Clean order infos
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;

# Clean cart infos
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;

# Reset indexes (if you want your orders number start back to 1
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_invoice_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_order_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_shipment_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_creditmemo_1;


SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```
````

### Method #2 M2 source code:

```
 protected function massAction(DbAC $collection)
    {
        if ($this->helper->isEnabled()) {
            $orderDeleted = 0;
            foreach ($collection as $order) {
                $this->orderRepository->deleteById($order->getId());
                $orderDeleted++;
            }
            if ($orderDeleted) {
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) were deleted.', $orderDeleted));
            }
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Delete Order module is Disabled'));
        }
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setPath($this->getComponentRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
```

See controller: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-delete-orders/blob/master/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Delete.php

Learn more https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-delete-orders .

Comment: Does source code method delete too related entities, such as invoice, shipment, etc...?

Comment: Yes sure. Delete related billing documents

Answer (score 0):

Delete a range of items, can be done in `n98-magerun2 dev:console`

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$registery = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');

foreach(range(4000000010, 4000000100) as $id) {
    $order = $objectManager->create( 'Magento\Sales\Model\Order' )->loadByIncrementId( $id );
    $registery->register( 'isSecureArea', 'true' );
    $order->delete();
    $registery->unregister( 'isSecureArea' );
}
```

Comment: Does this delete too related entities, such as invoice, shipment, etc...?

Answer (score -1):

**Truncate order tables**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `gift_message`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `reporting_orders`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_updated`;
```