# How to delete orders in Magento 2.2.1 without any extension?

Tags: magento2, orders, api, order-status, delete

I tried to **delete** my **order list** but could not delete those orders and searched on google. They provide the solutions with the use of an extension but I do not want to use extension. I would like to have a good way of doing it programatically.

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172945/how-to-delete-an-order-programatically-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 **focuses on use of API** primarily for **CRUD operation** so you may proceed as follows:
**Inject OrderInterface** in your class.

```
protected $order;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,
    ......
) {
    $this->order = $order;

}
```

Load order object by **increment id**, and delete it.

> Increment id and order id are completely **different entities** so do not
>   confuse with them.

Create a method within your class as:

```
function deleteOrderByIncrementId($incrementId = null )
{
    if($incrementId){
        $this->order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
        $this->order->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jaimin I do not think he is looking for this.