# How we can delete Magento 2 order programmatically?

Tags: magento2, orders, delete

I want to delete orders and associated data from my store programmatically. Share any idea, How can we do that?

Comment: @PrashantPatel let me check, if it solve my problem.

Comment: Try this  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/189755/48571

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory`.

```
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $order **/

protected $order;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $order,
    ......
) {
    $this->order = $order->create();

}
```

for getting order you can use.

```
$order = $this->order->loadByIncrementId('XXXXXXXXX');
// delete all invoices related to order
$invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();    
foreach($invoices as $invoice){
    $invoice->delete();
}

// delete all shipments related to order
$shipments = $order->getShipmentsCollection();
foreach($shipments as $shipment){
    $shipment->delete();
}


//delete all creditmemos related to order
$creditmemos = $order->getCreditmemosCollection();
foreach($creditmemos as $creditmemo){
    $creditmemo->delete();
}

// finally delete order
$order->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');

$id = 10; // your order_id 
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($id);

// $incrementId = 'xxxxxxxxx';
// $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

$registry->register('isSecureArea','true');
$order->delete();
$registry->unregister('isSecureArea');
```

I have shared with Object Manager but always use use dependency injection.

Comment: If you are using the answer of others, give credit to them.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/189755/48571